# Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid. occurred ERROR in Xamarin

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a SwitchCell implemented within a ListView; I want to be able to access the properties of the SwitchCell: On and text. I want to be able to get and set the OnProperty of the SwitchCell to change/read the Switch state from within the xaml.cs class.

when I run the code, I get the Unhandled Exception error. i am very new to both Xamarin and C# so any help/advise/examples of solving the problem will be greatly appreciated.

The exception is happening at **var selectedItem = ((SwitchCell)sender).BindingContext as Relays;** in the SwitchCell.xaml.cs.

My Relay.cs class is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace Socket.Models
{
    public class Relays
    {
      public Boolean isOn { get; set; }       // Set the state of the 
                                                switch 

      public string State { get; set; }       // Get the state of the 
                                     switch based on the isOn property

      public string Name { get; set; }        // Set the name of the 
                                               relay in the list

      }
   }
```

My SwitchCell.xaml is as follows:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
      <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="Socket.SwitchCell"
         Title="Relay Control Page">

<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout Padding="10,0,0,0">

        <ListView x:Name="lstView" SelectionMode="None">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <SwitchCell x:Name="Sw1" Text="{Binding Name}" On=" 
                             {Binding isOn, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                                OnChanged="SwitchCell_OnChanged_2"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>

        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

My SwitchCell.xaml.cs is as follows:

```
  using Socket.Models;
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
  using System.ComponentModel;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Runtime.CompilerServices; 
  using System.Text;
  using System.Threading.Tasks;
  using Xamarin.Forms;
  using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace Socket
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]

public partial class SwitchCell : ContentPage
{

    public SwitchCell ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
        loadSampleData();
    }

    private void loadSampleData()
    {
        // Create sample data

        ObservableCollection<Relays> listRelays = new 
          ObservableCollection<Relays>();

        listRelays.Add(new Relays { Name ="Relay 1", State = "", 
                 isOn=false });
        listRelays.Add(new Relays { Name ="Relay 2", State = "", 
                 isOn=false });
        listRelays.Add(new Relays { Name ="Relay 3", State = "", 
                 isOn=false });

        lstView.ItemsSource = listRelays;

    }

    private void SwitchCell_OnChanged_2(object sender, ToggledEventArgs 
                                                                e)
    {
        var selectedItem = ((SwitchCell)sender).BindingContext as 
                                        Relays;

        if (true)
        {            
            bool IsToggled = e.Value;
            string name = IsToggled.ToString();

            if (name == "True")
            {
                //DisplayAlert("ON", "Relay 1 On", "Cancel");
                BackgroundColor = Color.Silver;

                if (selectedItem.isOn == false)
                {
                    BackgroundColor = Color.Gold;
                    selectedItem.Name = "Changed";
                }
            }

            else
            {
                //DisplayAlert("OFF", "Relay 1 OFF", "Cancel");
                BackgroundColor = Color.LightSkyBlue;
            }

            }

        }       

    }

}
```

This is the error I get in VS 2017: **Unhandled Exception:
System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid. occurred**.

I am not sure if this is useful but this is what I get from the **Call Stack**:

> 0x1 in Socket.SwitchCell.SwitchCell_OnChanged_2 at C:\Users\ryno\Desktop\Xamarin\Socket\Socket\Socket\SwitchCell.xaml.cs:42,13.

I have no idea what I am doing wrong. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: the debugger should show you which line caused the exception.  Or, is it happening immediately when the page loads, or only after you do something?

Comment: Can you copy and paste the error and the stacktrace. that should help

Comment: Try renaming the page class (both in xaml and the codebehind) to something other than `SwitchCell`... (there is probably a name collision with the XAML ListView SwitchCell control)

Comment: It is happening at this line var selectedItem = ((SwitchCell)sender).BindingContext as Relays. Sorry, I forgot to add that to the question.

Comment: @Benl, I willl try and rename the page, thank you

Comment: @user1 I have added the call stack, not sure if it is useful though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it was my naming. Thank you for all your help @Gerald Versluis and for your suggestion @Benl.

Answer (score 1):

Only cast that seems to happen is here: `var selectedItem = ((SwitchCell)sender).BindingContext as Relays;`

Check if `sender` is indeed a `SwitchCell`.

Comment: How do I do that? Sorry but I am very new to C#. I found the line in question as an answer in this stackoverflow  [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44410601/execute-command-switchcell-onchanged-in-a-listview?rq=1)

Comment: Put a breakpoint on that line and hover over the `sender` variable to see what kind of object it is.

Comment: The sender is: sender {Xamarin.Forms.SwitchCell}. Is this useful? The var **selectedItem** is null though, why would this happen?

Comment: Strange. So, that checks out. What about the `BindingContext` property? Is that a `Relays`?

Comment: Is there a specific way to see that as it doesn't have any "value" assigned to it or are you asking what is the Relays referring to?

Comment: You could break it up: `var selectedItem = ((SwitchCell)sender);` and then: `var context = selectedItem.BindingContext as Relays;`. Although, you are using the `as` keyword, it shouldn't throw an exception.

Comment: i did the split and still get an error at this line: _var selectedItem = ((SwitchCell)sender);_ . I have no idea what could be the cause of this.

Comment: Weird, to rule out things, maybe add: `if (sender == null) return;`